# Getting exception that caused program to crash without being in debug mode

Tags: c#

I have an application in C# that I want to run by just running the .exe from my desktop.  However,  I'm pretty sure there will be some type of error that will make the program crash.  Is there a way to write the problem that caused the program to crash to a text file, so that I can see what caused the issue when users are using the program?  I know I can use debug mode to do this but I want to run the application as a stand alone not inside of VS.

Thanks,

I am aware of the try catch blocks and I am already using those where problems might occur.  But I am speaking in general.  For example if I wasn't sure where the problem would occur.  There is no way to print this specific error to a file.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the global try/catch method except that if there is an exception on a background thread it won't be caught. You can use `AppDomain.UnhandledException` if you want to be notified of any unhandled exception in the appdomain ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)). You would signup in main before the rest of your program executes like so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  AppDomain.UnhandledException += WriteUnhandledExceptionToFile;

  // rest of program
}

static void WriteUnhandledExceptionToFile(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
   // write to where ever you can get it.
   string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "UnhandledException.txt");
   File.WriteAllText(path, args.ExceptionObject.ToString()); // will print message and full stack trace.
}
```

Edit

Note that by default Windows Forms and WPF catch any exceptions that are thrown on the UI thread. You will have to subscribe to the Application.ThreadException event (forms) or Application.DispatcherUnhandledException event (wpf) to be notified of exceptions on those threads. The code would be very similar to the code above for the AppDomain event.

Answer (score 0):

Have a global exception handler that writes the exception details to a file.

If you wrap the code in your `Main` method in a `try{}catch{}` block, you can write out the exception details in the `catch` block.

```
try
{
  // Calls to application code
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // log `ex.ToString()`
   throw; // rethrow to ensure termination optionally: `Application.Exit`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can surround your one of the starting method with try catch block

```
try
{
   ///Your code
}
catch(Exception exception)
{
   System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("ErrLog.txt", exception.Message);
}
```

As a permanent solution you can create extension method ToLog and use it whenever you want.

```
public static void ToLog(this Exception Exception)
{
        using (var file = File.AppendText("ErrorLog.txt"))
        {
           file.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " : " + exception.Message);
        }
}
```

You can use it in catch block like this

```
 catch(Exception exception)
 {
    exception.ToLog();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you aren't logging the problem, you can usually get the error in question from the event viewer within windows.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to look at is [the `try/catch` construct in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx).  This is probably your first building block to handling errors.

As for how you *handle* the errors, that's entirely up to you.  Currently your only stated goal is to log them to a file.  You can get a lot of details out of the `Exception` object that you catch and you can [write those details to a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx).  Additionally, you can use [logging](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) [libraries](http://nlog-project.org/) to help with that sort of thing.

Proper error handling is something of a big subject, really.  One thing to keep in mind is logically *where* you want to catch the exception.  Ideally, you want to catch it where you can *handle* it.  That is, where your code can sufficiently recover from the error.  If it's a fatal error and the application should stop entirely, then you can `throw` the exception further up the stack and let it go unhandled (though still logged where you caught it).

If, however, you're in a logical condition where you can just log the error and move on, then the `catch` block allows you to do just that.  Log the details, update the state of any objects/data which need to be updated, and continue with the flow of the application.

Comment: @user541597: In that case you'll want to use a global exception handler.  Where you would put that depends on what kind of application it is.  For example, in an ASP.NET application it would be in the `Application_Error` method in `Global.asax`.  For a Windows Forms application it would be a handling of `System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException`.  For a console application it would probably just be a `try/catch` around the content of the `Main` method.

Answer (score 0):

See initial information here http://www.csharp-examples.net/catching-unhandled-exceptions/

```
static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message, "Unhandled Thread Exception");
}

static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show((e.ExceptionObject as Exception).Message, "Unhandled UI Exception");
}
```

The UnhandledException event handles uncaught exceptions thrown from the main UI thread. The ThreadException event handles uncaught exceptions thrown from non-UI threads.

I would replace the MessageBox with some actual logging (log4net or others).  This would give you the ability to log out the errors to another server for distributed applications, file system for local users, event logs, options are fairly unlimited if you're willing to put in the time.